# Specify the application base path in ConfigurationBuilder in beta8

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core

I used to specify the application base path for the `ConfigurationBuilder` like this:

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
}
```

However, as of beta8, the constructor of `ConfigurationBuilder` does not take an application base path argument anymore and it throws an exception now.

How can I specify the base path?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we look at the [source code of `ConfigurationBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/1.0.0-beta8/src/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration/ConfigurationBuilder.cs), we can see that the constructor no longer accepts a string representing the application base path. In stead, we have to use the [`SetBasePath()` extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/1.0.0-beta8/src/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.FileExtensions/FileConfigurationExtensions.cs) on the `IConfigurationBuilder` interface to specify it:

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
}
```

The particular commit can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/commit/bf62a69de10a50f01ddc4b9049abe8572c4995d8#diff-eaa00df041a94f159a5154d9a19a3910R17).

Comment: Sorry if the question is very late but how do you add the IApplicationEnvironment? I am searching for hours now and can't get it working.. I am pretty new to C#. If I want to inject the IApplicationEnvironment it says that it couldn't be found?

Comment: As well I am following a tutorial. He is using the "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration" and if I include this into my project I can't apply the ".AddEnviromentVariables()" method. In order to do this I need the "using Microsoft.Extension.Configuration". But this doen't allow me to use the IApplicationEnviroment??

Comment: What version do you use @Anokrize? RC1 or RC2? The `IApplicationEnvironment` class lives in the `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` namespace.

Comment: Why doesn't this appear in Core 2?