# ASP.NET 5 Config File not opening

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, asp.net-core, configuration-files

I've created a static class to use my configurations, but when I try to add the JSON file to the configuration I got an exception:

MyConfigurations.json:

```
{ "ConnectionString": "my connection string", ...}
```

My static class constructor:

```
static MyConfigurations() {
    var configuration = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("MyConfigurations.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    ...
    ...
```

My exception occurs when the `.AddJsonFile` is executed.

Exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

StackTrace:

> at
>   Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.PathResolver.get_ApplicationBaseDirectory()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.JsonConfigurationExtension.AddJsonFile(IConfigurationSourceRoot
>   configuration, String path, Boolean optional) at
>   Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.JsonConfigurationExtension.AddJsonFile(IConfigurationSourceRoot
>   configuration, String path) at
>   Project.SharedKernel.MyConfigurations..cctor() in
>   C:\Project\Project.SharedKernel\MyConfigurations.cs:line 86

Comment: Does anyone mind sharing why they downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set the *application base path* which the configuration API needs to determine where the physical config files live. You can set it using the `SetBasePath` extension method. A typical implementation looks like this:

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("MyConfigurations.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

Note: this only counts for beta8, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33169589). You don't have to specify the default base path anymore in RC1: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/88.

Comment: I'm trying to load this configuration in another project, in a class library with a static class to be shared with all projects of my solution, there is a way to work in this scenary?

Comment: Just as a note: In RC1 the base bath is not longer needed: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/88

Comment: @Cesar I think your best option is to pass the `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath` to the static class.