# How to SetBasePath in ConfigurationBuilder in Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-core

How can I set the base path in ConfigurationBuilder in Core 2.0.

I have googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169589/specify-the-application-base-path-in-configurationbuilder-in-beta8) question, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration) from Microsoft docs, and the [2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_FileConfigurationExtensions_SetBasePath_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_System_String_) docs online but they seem to be using a version of `Microsoft.Extension.Configuration` from [1.0.0-beta8](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/1.0.0-beta8/src/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.FileExtensions/FileConfigurationExtensions.cs).

I want to read `appsettings.json`. Is there a new way of doing this in Core 2.0?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // <== compile failing here
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            Configuration = builder.Build();

            Console.WriteLine(Configuration.GetConnectionString("con"));
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**appsetting.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "con": "connection string"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
In addition to adding [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions/) as indicated below by [Set](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2833802/set) I also needed to add [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) to get the `AddJsonFile` extension.

Comment: The UPDATE made the work!

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` has a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`, so you just need the former.

Comment: Friends, PLEASE NOTE, the `AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")` method is not aware of your hosting environment!  Use `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json")` instead.  :D

Answer (score 449, accepted):

The [`SetBasePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath) extension method is defined in [Config.FileExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Config.FileExtensions/FileConfigurationExtensions.cs#L60).

You need to add a reference to the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions/) package.

To resolve [`AddJsonFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile), add a reference to the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) package.

Comment: But now the "AddJsonFile" method is not found. :D I had to add this package also: "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json".

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` has a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`, so you just need the former.

Comment: do manage the nuget packages on solution level not the project level

Answer (score 81):

I'm developing a .NET Core 2 console app using Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.  As others have noted, after adding Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration I needed to add Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json to get the `AddJsonFile()` call to work.  This also made the `SetBasePath()` call work; so I **did not need** to add **Configuration.FileExtensions** .  (My code compiles and runs both with and without it.)

I also had a call to `AddEnvironmentVariables()`, for which I needed to add Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.  My code is as follows:

```
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // requires Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json") // requires Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables(); // requires Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
  Configuration = builder.Build();
```

Interestingly, the only `using` statement I needed was `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.

Comment: The only using statement necessary in the class file should be Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. However, to the project you must explicitly add the NuGet dependency "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" via Manage NuGet Packages project option. A dependency of this is "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" and will therefore be included as part of the dependency wire-up. These two dependencies will solve both the "SetBasePath" and "AddJsonFile" compilation errors.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this no longer works as VS for Mac Preview 8 sets the current directory to bin/netcoreapp2x

Comment: Not to be pedantic but `Configuration.EnvironmentVariables` == `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables`.  There are several things with similar names.

Answer (score 15):

Use both 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json' this will solve the problem.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/

Here is the sample 'ConnectionFactory'

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace DataAccess.Infrastructure
{
 public class ConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
 {
    public ConnectionFactory()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }


    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
    public IDbConnection GetConnection
    {
        get
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }


            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~ConnectionFactory() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding reference if you are still unable to get the content of JSON.

Go to in properties of JSON (right-click on JSON file > properties)
change "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always"

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjNM2.png)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you stumbling upon this while using .NET 8.

You'll need to following packages:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And the following using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Now in your program.cs you can:

```
    // Build the configuration
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: false) // Use the specified environment's file
        .Build();
```

More information in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration).