# Seperate appsettings.json and all other files to different directories when publishing

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, dotnet-publish

I need to separate my `appsettings.json` file and one other `.json` file which i use for app configuration from all other files when i publish the app.
The out put should be that all files will be at .bin folder which is now the folder destination of the publish profile and the .json files should be at CFG folder which will be at the same level as the bin folder

Comment: If you've known where the config root folder is, you can change its via `.SetBasePath`. See this SO [how-to-setbasepath-in-configurationbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843367/how-to-setbasepath-in-configurationbuilder-in-core-2-0) to take a look.

Comment: I already reading the file from that location. It works fine. The problem is that I'm manually copying the files from published folder to that path after publish

Comment: Understood now. Then goto your csproj, try put `<None Include="CFG\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" LinkBase="CFG\" />` in `ItemGroup` section. Use `PreserveNewest ` or `Always` syntax depends on your needs.

Comment: Managed to achieve it with post build events