# How to access appsettings.json globally in other classes using .Net 5 Core

Tags: c#, .net

I need access to the appsettings.json configuration in other non-controller classes in my project. Is there a good way for IConfiguration to be available globally throughout my application w/o using DI? If the IConfiguration DI could be used on non-controller classes, I'd like to know how to do that.

This is my controller where HostService has access to the IConfiguration injection.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<HostService>();
        }).UseSerilog();
}
```

I need access to IConfiguration in this non-controller class. I'm not sure how to use the DI w/ non-controller type classes, so maybe using a static type configuration variable would be a better solution to make IConfiguration available globally.

```cs
public class myTestClass 
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config

    public myTestClass(IConfiguration config){ _config = config}
}
```

Comment: Using Dependency Injection is one of the best approaches
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned, it's using the Startup class which I'm not using in my current build, so I need to figure out a way to do it w/o using that class. Is there a way to do the Dependency Injection using the current controller I'm using above w/o the Startup class?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use Startup or not.
You can simply `services.AddScoped<IConfigurationRoot>(()=>{buil your configuration});`
and then Inject where you want.

also take a look at ConfigurationBuilder

Comment: here is an example of ConfigurationBuilder, if you don't want inject.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843367/how-to-setbasepath-in-configurationbuilder-in-core-2-0

Comment: The whole point of DI is to inject your dependencies... I think you need to do more learning on what and why to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a way to make IConfiguration available throughout the application without using Injections. It's quite pointless to use IConfiguration DI for non-controller classes since it requires too many steps. Just create a static class w/ a static IConfiguration variable and assign the Iconfiguration injection parameter to it from the main controller class and it'll be available throughout the app. It's simple and easy.

Programs.cs

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            {
                return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseWindowsService()
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddHostedService<HostService>();
                    }).UseSerilog();
            }
```

HostService.cs

```
        public static class AppData
        {
            public static IConfiguration Config;
        }
        public class HostService : IHostedService, IDisposable
        {
            public HostSyncService(IConfiguration config)
            {
                AppData.Config = config;

                var key= new myTestClass().getKey();
            }
        }
```

myTestClass.cs

```
        public class myTestClass {
            public myTestClass(){}
            
            public void getKey(){
                // Non-Controller class has access to AppData.Config w/o injection
                var key= AppData.Config.GetValue<string>("appSettings:key");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a configuration to you DI container by adding a handling of config to you host:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<HostService>();
        })
        .UseSerilog();
}
```

It makes the whole `IConfiguration` object available for your application:

```
public class TestOptions
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class HostService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public HostService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _configuration = config;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // TODO: write your code here
    }
}
```

> I need access to IConfiguration in this custom class. I can pass an IConfiguration instance in from the HostService class, but was looking for global solution to avoid passing instances to other classes.

Dependency Injection solves a lot of different issues, and today it is a common way to develop software. It is much easier to use DI instead of avoid using it.

Comment: I agree w/ the DI container idea totally which already worked fine on my current build  w/ HostService. The question I have is, how can other classes in other files use the DI container feature the same way. Currently, with a class in another file, I have to pass the _config from the HostService into the constructor since it doesn’t use the injection like HostService does. For example, I have to do this, myTestClass test = new myTestClass(_config) for constructor myTestClass(IConfiguration config){} which works ok, but would like it to work the same as the HostService class if possible. Tnx.

Comment: Why not define that class as a service too? You could define it as scoped & create a new scope around where you are using it. You haven't given sufficient context and reasoning to describe why you aren't using DI. Step back and explain the actual problem.